# Can we use ArgumentCaptor to check log message in Mockito

Tags: mockito, atg

I have a form handler in ATG having following handle method -

```
    public boolean handleFindCards(DynamoHttpServletRequest pRequest, DynamoHttpServletResponse pResponse)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    Card card = cardService.getCard();

    if (card == null) {
         if (isLoggingError()) {
             logError("Card Service is null");
         }
    } else {
        // Other code
    }

    return checkFormRedirect(getSuccessURL(), getSuccessURL(), pRequest, pResponse);
}
```

Form handler is using logging from one of it's super class **GenericService**. I want to write a test to check if cardService is null. In above code when card service is null, it's writing an error message using logError. Can we use ArgumentCaptor here to verify the message. OR is there any other way to test this scenario?

Here, how mocking and spying will work together? I should stub the call for getting card object as -

```
when(cardServiceMock.getCard()).thenReturn(cardMock);
```

This is my test method -

```
    @Test
    public void testHandleCardServiceIfCardIsNull() throws IOException, ServletException {
        CardService cardServiceMock = mock(CardService.class);
        when(cardServiceMock.getCard()).thenReturn(null);

        CardOperationsFormHandler testObjSpy = spy(new CardOperationsFormHandler());
        testObjSpy.handleFindCards(requestMock, responseMock);
        ArgumentCaptor<String> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        Mockito.verify(testObjSpy).logError(argumentCaptor.capture());
        Assert.assertEquals(argumentCaptor.getValue(), "Card Service is null");
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is `logError` in the superclass final?  If not, you could use a spy.  Let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: Superclass is not final. I have used spy() but getting error as [Wanted but not invoked:
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.]

Comment: I think you'll need to post the code of your test before anyone can figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David Wallace has said, you'll need to use `Mockito.spy(T object)`.

So with a simple method:

```
public void runArgumentCaptor() {
    logError("This is an error");
}
```

The test can look like this:

```
    @Spy @InjectMocks private SomeClassName testObj;

    @Test(groups = { "unit" })
    public void runArgumentCaptorTest() throws Exception {

        testObj.runArgumentCaptor();

        ArgumentCaptor<String> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        Mockito.verify(testObj).logError(argumentCaptor.capture());
        Assert.assertEquals(argumentCaptor.getValue(), "This is an error");
    }
```

**[EDIT]**
Added the declaration of `testObj`. Note the additional `@Spy`. Also updated the test method.

Comment: Thanks radimpe. This is fine but how mocking and spying would work together. In my case my stubs are not working and I am getting null pointer. I have edited the question. Please check.

Comment: @Saurabh: Add the `@Spy` annotation and you can do both Mocking and Spying.

Comment: I would replace the last three lines of your test with `verify(testObj).logError("This is an error");` - you really don't need the argument captor.

Answer (score 1):

It's working now. As radimpe said I have replaced mock with spy. So, here I am creating cardServiceSpy instead of cardServiceMock and then using stub. Also, need to use doReturn for stubbing. Here is the method -

```
    @Test
    public void testHandleCardServiceIfCardIsNull() throws IOException, ServletException {
        CardService cardServiceSpy = spy(new CardService());
        doReturn(null).when(cardServiceSpy).getCard();

        CardOperationsFormHandler testObjSpy = spy(new CardOperationsFormHandler());
        testObjSpy.handleFindCards(requestMock, responseMock);
        ArgumentCaptor<String> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        Mockito.verify(testObjSpy).logError(argumentCaptor.capture());
        Assert.assertEquals(argumentCaptor.getValue(), "Card Service is null");
    }
```

Comment: This is a little more complex than it needs to be.  (1) If you use the @Spy annotation, you can avoid explicitly instantiating the objects that you're spying on.  (2) An argument captor is pointless here - you can just verify the string argument directly.  It's also not clear why you are spying the `CardService` and why you are stubbing out `getCard()`.  Do you really need to do those things?

Comment: @David, agree with your 1st point. I am stubbing getCard() because, it's doing a real call on cardService and throwing null pointer.

Comment: Really?  Because `cardServiceSpy` is not being used after the first two lines of your test method.  So those two lines effectively do nothing.  Have you tried running this test with those two lines removed?  Also, I strongly recommend you replace the last three lines with the one line that I gave under radimpe's answer.  I am very much in favour of having very concise tests, so that I can browse through the test class and see exactly what has and hasn't been tested, without getting bogged down in noise.

Comment: Thanks David. I have removed two lines and replaced ArgumentCaptor with verify as you suggested. My test is running fine. Just one thing, if cardService would have been used somewhere then we need to write stub correct?

Comment: That would really depend on HOW `CardService` is used.  Sometimes, you'll want to use a real one; sometimes a mock; sometimes a spy.  You need to think about what you are actually trying to test, and whether the functionality of `CardService` is relevant to it.  Unit testing can be a bit of an art sometimes, but it's the kind of thing that you get better at with practice.